# CSS android and iOS problem

Tags: android, css, ios, mobile, mobile-safari

When i try to stretch a div 100% there is a little line at the end in iOS and Android. Here's  a pic for better view:

[image: screenshot]

I searched all over the net but i didn't find a solution.

```
<html>  
<head>  
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=0.666" />  
<style>  
html, body {  
    position:relative;  
    height:100%;  
    width:100%;  
    padding:0;  
    margin:0;  
    overflow-x:hidden; 
}  
header {  
    width: 100%;  
    background: red;  
    height: 50px;  
    display: block;  
    margin: 0;  
    padding: 0;  
    overflow-x:hidden;  
}  
</style>  
</head>  
<body>  
<header>asdasd</header>  
</body>  
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's probably the space reserved for a scrollbar.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
header {  
    width: 100%;  
    background: red;  
    height: 50px;  
    display: block;  
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    overflow-x:hidden;  
}
```

Then to make sure your content doesn't wind up under the header due to absolute positioning, give the body tag the same top padding as the height of the header:

```
html, body {  
    position:relative;  
    height:100%;  
    width:100%;  
    padding:50px 0 0;  
    margin:0;  
    overflow-x:hidden; 
}
```